# Kendo Grid with virtual scrolling & grid footer with total items

Tags: kendo-grid

I can't find a way so it's possible to show the grid footer with:

> 1 - 20 of xx items

and refresh button too, when I use:

```
scrollable: { virtual: true }
```

in the Kendo Grid?

Answer (score 1):

Try these attributes in your datasource:

```
    scrollable: { virtual: true },
     pageable:{
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: [20, 50, 100, 200]
     },
```

Have a look at this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/R4vdDvQwgcSUw0jO7Qzv?p=preview

Comment: Did you ever use this feature in a productive environment? Officially, this is not supported (see "Either enable virtual scrolling or paging. Do not apply both features at the same time." on http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#limitations-of-virtual-scrolling). But it seems to work quite fine with the version from 2014 as well with the latest one.

Comment: I forgot that I could simply ask Telerik's support. I've asked them if "The suggestion not to use both at the same time is not from a technical point? There is no known limitation/issue when using both together?"

Comment: The answer is good enough for me: "The both features will work together without breaking or any JavaScript errors and etc.

But they are generally not in sync:
* If you scroll, the pager will update. 
* But if you change the page using the pager, the scroll will not update. 

Because they are not two-way synchronized, we suggest you to avoid using them at the same time (to avoid confusion in end users). But if such behavior is acceptable for you, feel free to enable both features."